# Trouble with Thread.Sleep(0)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I tried to test the context switch using Thread.Sleep(0) using this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadMethod
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void ThreadMethod()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);

                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));

            t.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main Thread here!");

                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }



            t.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

but result was the following:

> Main Thread here! 
>   ThreadProc: 0 
>   ThreadProc: 1 
>   ThreadProc: 2 
>   ThreadProc: 3 
>   ThreadProc: 4 
>   ThreadProc: 5 
>   ThreadProc: 6 
>   ThreadProc: 7 
>   ThreadProc: 8 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   Main Thread here! 
>   ThreadProc: 9

I am developing on Surface PRO 2. Is this behaviour due to a multicore system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3257751/961113

Comment: This may be a great educational question for learning the threading model, but for production, I would highly recommend using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread.Sleep(0) : What is the normal behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257708/thread-sleep0-what-is-the-normal-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a context switch, you should give low priority to your Thread / use `Thread.Sleep(1)`, also you can read more on this on the similar question: [Thread.Sleep(0) : What is the normal behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257708/thread-sleep0-what-is-the-normal-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [Thread.Yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This will signal OS that the current thread doesn't need the CPU time anymore and will make the OS switch to another thread if one is waiting.

Answer (score -1):

if you want context switch, try `Thread.Sleep()` with something other than Zero.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257708/thread-sleep0-what-is-the-normal-behavior) - have good answers